# Int Comparison of string in android

Tags: java, android, swift

Hi I’m trying to write the below in swift. This works just fine with firebase and ios i can message and all. The only issue for ios is when I try to view a message made in android but this I think is because of the timestamp. Please help with the fixing this on android.

```
    import Foundation
import Firebase
import UIKit

struct ChatFunctions {

    var chatRoom_id = String()
    var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!


    mutating func startChat(user1: User3, user2: User3) {

        let userId1 = user1.uid
        let userId2 = user2.uid

        var chatRoomId: String = ""

        let comparison = userId1?.compare(userId2!).rawValue

        let members = ["user1": user1.username, "user2": user2.username]

        if comparison! < 0 {
            chatRoomId = userId1! + userId2!
        } else {
            chatRoomId = userId2! + userId1!
        }

        self.chatRoom_id = chatRoomId
        self.createChatRoomId(user1: user1, user2: user2, members: members, chatRoomId: chatRoomId)

    }


    private func createChatRoomId(user1: User3, user2: User3, members: [String: String?], chatRoomId: String) {

        let chatRoomRef = Database.database().reference().child("ChatRooms").queryOrdered(byChild: "chatRoomId").queryEqual(toValue: chatRoomId)

        chatRoomRef.observe(.value , with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

            var createChatRoom = true

            if snapshot.exists() {

                if let values = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    for chatRoom in values {

                        if let room = chatRoom.value["chatRoomId"] as? String  {
                            if room == chatRoomId {
                                createChatRoom = false
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if createChatRoom == true {
                self.createNewChatRoom(user1: user1, user2: user2, members: members, chatRoomId: chatRoomId, lastMessage: "", userProfilePic: user1.profilePic!, other_UserProfilePic: user2.profilePic!, date:NSNumber(value: Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
            }

        }) { (error) in
            alerts().errorAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, duration: 1)
        }

    }

    private func createNewChatRoom(user1: User3, user2: User3, members: [String: String?], chatRoomId: String, lastMessage: String, userProfilePic: String, other_UserProfilePic: String, date: NSNumber) {

        let newChatRoom = ChatRoom(username: user1.username!, other_Username: user2.username!, userId: user1.uid!, other_UserId: user2.uid!, members: members, chatRoomId: chatRoomId, lastMessage: lastMessage, userProfilePic: userProfilePic, other_UserProfilePic: other_UserProfilePic, date: date)

        let chatRoomRef = Database.database().reference().child("ChatRooms").child(chatRoomId)
        chatRoomRef.setValue(newChatRoom.toAnyObject())

    }

}
```

Here is the android version of the code. For some reason it clears out any data saved on the server for that chat room when I try to open the chatroom on android. I looks like it loops at checking if the chatroom was already they or not but still creates it.

```
public class ChatFunctions implements Parcelable {

private String chatRoom_id;
private FirebaseDatabase database;

public ChatFunctions() {
}

public ChatFunctions(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

public ChatFunctions(String chatRoom_id) {
    this.chatRoom_id = chatRoom_id;
}

public String getChatRoom_id() {
    return chatRoom_id;
}

public void setChatRoom_id(String chatRoom_id) {
    this.chatRoom_id = chatRoom_id;
}


public void startChat(User3 user1, User3 user2) {
    String userId1 = user1.getUid();
    String userId2 = user2.getUid();

    String chatRoomId;

    int comparison = userId1.compareTo(userId2);
    Map<String, Object> members1 = new HashMap<>();
    members1.put("user1", user1.getUsername());
    members1.put("user2", user2.getUsername());

    if (comparison < 0) {
        chatRoomId = userId1 + userId2;
    } else {
        chatRoomId = userId2 + userId1;
    }


    setChatRoom_id(chatRoomId);


    createChatRoomId(user1, user2, members1, chatRoomId);

}

private void createChatRoomId(final User3 user1, final User3 user2, final Map<String, Object> members, final String chatRoomId) {
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

     database.getReference().child("ChatRooms").orderByChild("chatRoomId").equalTo(chatRoomId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        boolean createChatRoom = true;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                for (Object chatRoom : values.values()) {
                    String room = chatRoom.toString();
                    if (room.equals(chatRoomId)) {
                        createChatRoom = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                createChatRoom = true;
                Log.v("Room", "true");
            }

            if (createChatRoom == true) {
                createNewChatRoom(user1, user2, members, chatRoomId, "", user1.getProfilePic(), user2.getProfilePic(), new Date().getTime() * 1000);
                Log.v("Room", "false");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
private void createNewChatRoom(User3 user1, User3 user2, Map<String, Object> members, String chatRoomId, String lastMessage, String userProfilePic, String other_UserProfilePic, Long date) {
    DefaultDialogModel newChatRoom = new DefaultDialogModel(user1.getUsername(), user2.getUsername(), user1.getUid(), user2.getUid(), members, chatRoomId, userProfilePic, lastMessage, other_UserProfilePic, date);
    DatabaseReference chatRoomRef = database.getReference().child("ChatRooms").child(chatRoomId);
    chatRoomRef.setValue(newChatRoom);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(chatRoom_id);
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    chatRoom_id = in.readString();
}


public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<ChatFunctions>() {

    @Override
    public ChatFunctions createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new ChatFunctions(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public ChatFunctions[] newArray(int i) {
        return new ChatFunctions[0];
    }

    @Override
    public ChatFunctions createFromParcel(Parcel parcel, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        return null;
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setValue` method in Android's Firebase API overwrites any existing values. To update values instead, use the `updateChildren` method [1].

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: Yes but that supposed to only be called if the chatroom doesn't exist. The loop happens on the check but from test the issue is within checking the usernames.

Comment: Are you referring to the Android line `int comparison = userId1.compareTo(userId2);` ?

Comment: Yes that is what I was referring to.

Comment: Looks like that may be fine. But in your Firebase listener, it seems as though `String room = chatRoom.toString();` may not be correct. Can you print out the value of `chatRoom.toString()`? Since you state it is an `Object`, it may not have the correct `toString` implementation and is not returning the desired room id.

Comment: when I print out the value it pulls the correct chatroom id but its pulling it about 10 times.

Comment: What class is the actual type of `chatRoom`? Can you make sure that the `chatroom.toString()` is in fact providing the correct output?

Comment: Its not a class the whole code is a model class for chat function. It pulls the chatroom id correctly. It just loops the id about 10 times.

Comment: `String room = chatRoom.toString();`

What is the value of room? Is it "roomidroomidroomid..."?

Comment: no it the id for userid1 and userid2 or it would be userid2 and userid1.

Comment: When does it loop 10 times then? I'm not understanding where the inconsistency is happening.

Comment: Where in your code, at what lines, does it loop 10 times?

Comment: When cchecking if the chatroom exists

Comment: ` for (Object chatRoom : values.values()) {` runs 10 times?

Comment: Yes that is where i am finding the issue.

Comment: With `for (Object chatRoom : values.values()) {` it runs 10 times.
So `String room = chatRoom.toString()` is run 10 times.
Is `room` always the same value?

Comment: No its not but the issue is there are only 2 chat rooms. show it should only run twice i thing its the way the for loop was made. In swift i did it as a for in loop but i cant in android

Comment: Should you just use `dataSnapshot.getValue()` without turning it into a `Map`?

Comment: I can try. Didn't think out that.

Comment: I tried didnt work. But i checked again without changing the code. It prints the same chatId

Comment: `dataSnapshot.getValue()` returns the chatId?

Comment: Yes but loops it. I changed the code for pulling from firebase and that works. Now just working on the chat part thanks for your help.